# How to write the dynamic source for image control in style for a button (APP.XAML) in silverlight 3?

Tags: image, version-control, dynamic, for-loop

How to write the dynamic source for image control in style for a button (APP.XAML) in silverlight 3?

Answer (score 0):

I work with WPF, not Silverlight (yet!), but it seems like this is 'core' enough it should be applicable in both WPF/Silverlight scenarios.  I could be wrong though! :)

Have you looked at using a [DataTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)?  This will allow you to style the source of the image based on a data value in your DataContext.

This sample assumes we've got a DataContext set with a Property called "Frame".  The Image.Source is set based on the value Frame.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style>
                    <!-- style the image source based on some property in our data context, though 
                    replace static paths with pack URL-->
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Frame}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="C:\dev\images\sample\image1.jpg"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Frame}" Value="2">
                            <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="C:\dev\images\sample\image2.jpg"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Instead of referring to the images using static file paths, you will want to replace with a pack:// uri.  See [Refer to Resources in WPF With a Pack URI](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124000119/http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/04/28/refer-to-resources-in-wpf-with-pack-uri.aspx) for more information.